# Sort results alphabetically in custom foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, foreach

I've modified a function I found to do what I need, although it works, unfortunately the results returned are not in any specific order, I need them to be alphabetical.

This script returns a list of subcategories from Woocommerce:

```
function get_product_subcategories_list( $category_slug ){
    $terms_html = array();
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    // Get the product category (parent) WP_Term object
    $parent = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_slug, $taxonomy );
    // Get an array of the subcategories IDs (children IDs)
    $children_ids = get_term_children( $parent->term_id, $taxonomy );

    // Loop through each children IDs
    foreach($children_ids as $children_id) {
        $term = get_term( $children_id, $taxonomy ); // WP_Term object
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); // The term link
        $thumbnail_id   = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) $term_link = '';
        // Set in an array the html formatted subcategory name/link
        $terms_html[] = '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</li></a>';
    }
    return '<ul>' . implode( $terms_html ) . '</ul>';
}
```

...and not that it matters, but this is in my template:

```
get_product_subcategories_list( $post->post_name );
```

The problem is that `$terms_html[]` is returning this...

```
<li><a href="https://example.com/pants">Pants</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/shoes">Shoes</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/hats">Hats</a></li>
```

...but I need it to be alphabetical like this:

```
<li><a href="https://example.com/hats">Hats</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/pants">Pants</a></li>
<li><a href="https://example.com/shoes">Shoes</a></li>
```

Comment: just use `sort()`: https://3v4l.org/UZX2q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [`get_term_children`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/) doesn't provide any way of sorting. Just treat the array with the sorting yourself.

Push the `->name` in the array as key pairs. Then just utilize `ksort()`. Like so:

```
foreach($children_ids as $children_id) {
    $term = get_term( $children_id, $taxonomy ); // WP_Term object
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); // The term link
    $thumbnail_id   = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) $term_link = '';
    // Set in an array the html formatted subcategory name/link
    $terms_html[$term->name] = '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</li></a>';
    //          ^^ push the term name as key
}

ksort($terms_html); // sort it
return '<ul>' . implode( $terms_html ) . '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `sort` function
like this

```
sort($terms_html)
foreach($terms_html as $item){
   echo $item;
}
```